# Is there any way to optimize the layout events?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, instruments

I used **Time Profile** to check what caused my app to become very stutter and stutter when quick change the `pageiwController's page`, and it detects that layout events take many CPU and Thread usage (pls see below 'pic'), it costs Max 182% CPU and Max 96% Thread resources, it must be unreasonable. they are system events, how can i optimize them?

Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

**code snippet 1: archors**

```
private func aulayoutViews() {
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
    view.addSubview(navigationBar)

    //MARK: navigationBar
    PageViewController.navigationBarHeight = 44

    navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    navigationBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
    navigationBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PageViewController.navigationBarHeight).isActive = true
    navigationBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    } else {
        navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }

    //MARK: pageControl
    PageViewController.pageControlHeight = 10

    pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pageControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
    pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PageViewController.pageControlHeight).isActive = true
    pageControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    pageControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

**code snippet 2: mainly stack view impelmentaion**

```
 private func layoutViews() {
    var updateTimeX: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    var updateTimeY: CGFloat = CGFloat()

    switch iPhoneType {
    case .iPhoneSE:
        updateTimeX = 0
        updateTimeY = 0
    case .iPhone:
        updateTimeX = 0
        updateTimeY = 8
    case .iPhonePlus:
        updateTimeX = 4
        updateTimeY = 8
    default: //case .iPhoneX:
        updateTimeX = 0
        updateTimeY = 8
    }

    //MARK: updateTime的autolayout
    self.view.addSubview(updateTime)
    updateTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    updateTime.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: updateTimeY).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-updateTimeX-[updateTime]",
        options: [],
        metrics: ["updateTimeX": updateTimeX],
        views: ["updateTime": updateTime]))

    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[stackView]-16-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["stackView": stackView]))

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentStackView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(buttonAQIStackView)
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 8

    contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(tempWeatherStackView)
    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(sunWindHumidityStackView)
    contentStackView.axis = .vertical
    contentStackView.alignment = .leading
    contentStackView.distribution = .fill
    contentStackView.spacing = -16

    tempWeatherStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tempWeatherStackView.addArrangedSubview(currentTemp)
    tempWeatherStackView.addArrangedSubview(currentWeather)
    tempWeatherStackView.axis = .horizontal
    tempWeatherStackView.alignment = .firstBaseline
    tempWeatherStackView.distribution = .fill
    tempWeatherStackView.spacing = -32

    sunWindHumidityStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sunWindHumidityStackView.addArrangedSubview(sunTime)
    sunWindHumidityStackView.addArrangedSubview(wind)
    sunWindHumidityStackView.addArrangedSubview(humidity)
    sunWindHumidityStackView.axis = .horizontal
    sunWindHumidityStackView.alignment = .top
    sunWindHumidityStackView.distribution = .fill
    sunWindHumidityStackView.spacing = 8

    weatherButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    weatherButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true

    AQIButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    AQIButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true

    buttonAQIStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonAQIStackView.addArrangedSubview(weatherButton)
    buttonAQIStackView.addArrangedSubview(AQIButton)
    buttonAQIStackView.axis = .horizontal
    buttonAQIStackView.alignment = .fill
    buttonAQIStackView.distribution = .fill
    buttonAQIStackView.spacing = 8
}
```

**code snippet 3: stack view & constrains**

```
private func layoutViews() {
    var iconImageSize: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    var stackWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    var scrollHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    var stackViewWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat()

    switch iPhoneType {
    case .iPhoneSE:
        iconImageSize = 29
        stackWidth = 79.5
        scrollHeight = 980
        stackViewWidth = stackWidthCalculateBy(stackWidth, totalStackQty: 16, sceneStackQty: 6, sceneSpacing: 16)
    case .iPhone:
        iconImageSize = 32
        stackWidth = 92
        scrollHeight = 109.76
        stackViewWidth = stackWidthCalculateBy(stackWidth, totalStackQty: 16, sceneStackQty: 6, sceneSpacing: 16)
    case .iPhonePlus:
        iconImageSize = 32
        stackWidth = 96
        scrollHeight = 122.24
        stackViewWidth = stackWidthCalculateBy(stackWidth, totalStackQty: 16, sceneStackQty: 6, sceneSpacing: 16)
    default: //case .iPhoneX:
        iconImageSize = 32
        stackWidth = 92
        scrollHeight = 109.76
        stackViewWidth = stackWidthCalculateBy(stackWidth, totalStackQty: 16, sceneStackQty: 6, sceneSpacing: 16)
    }

    //MARK: stackView
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|[stackView(scrollHeight)]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: ["scrollHeight": scrollHeight],
        views: ["stackView": stackView]))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[stackView(stackViewWidth)]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: ["stackViewWidth": stackViewWidth],
        views: ["stackView": stackView]))

    for index in 0...ix {
        tempStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(highTempLabel[index])
        tempStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(lowTempLabel[index])

        tempStackView[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tempStackView[index].axis = .vertical
        tempStackView[index].alignment = .fill
        tempStackView[index].distribution = .fillEqually

        iconImage[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconImage[index].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: iconImageSize).isActive = true
        iconImage[index].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62).isActive = true
        iconImage[index].contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        iconTempStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(iconImage[index])
        iconTempStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(tempStackView[index])

        iconTempStackView[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconTempStackView[index].axis = .horizontal
        iconTempStackView[index].alignment = .fill
        iconTempStackView[index].distribution = .fill

        weekLabel[index].setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .horizontal)
        weekDateStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(weekLabel[index])
        weekDateStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(dateLabel[index])

        weekDateStackView[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        weekDateStackView[index].axis = .horizontal
        weekDateStackView[index].alignment = .fill
        weekDateStackView[index].distribution = .fill
        weekDateStackView[index].spacing = 8

        contentStackView[index].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackWidth).isActive = true
        contentStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(weekDateStackView[index])
        contentStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(iconTempStackView[index])
        contentStackView[index].addArrangedSubview(weatherLabel[index])

        contentStackView[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentStackView[index].axis = .vertical
        contentStackView[index].alignment = .fill
        contentStackView[index].distribution = .equalSpacing

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(contentStackView[index])
    }

    //MARK: scrollView
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:[scrollView(scrollHeight)]|",
        options: [],
        metrics: ["scrollHeight": scrollHeight],
        views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))
}
```

Comment: You probably need to post more.... Code? Explanation? IB? Exactly **what** is a user doing (and please, include what code is being executed) when things "stutter"? For instance, today I've moved some `UIKit` code that created a new `CIImage` mask based on `UISlider` changes that relate to a color change into GLSL code inside a `CIKernel`. I understand, my issue isn't anything *like* your's, but that still leaves the question for you - what can *you* tell *me* so that I can reproduce whatever issue is causing your stuttering?

Comment: @dfd There’s no special for layout code, i put all layout relevant codes in one method for each different view controller class, and the main purpose for the method are: first add subviews, second auto layout subviews. The way used to layout views are anchor, stack view and constraints. Please see codes updated in the question description (PS: others that not showing are very similar to above).

Comment: @dfd All subviews will added to a scroll view’s content subview, after that the scroll view will be added to a content viewController’s view, which act as the PageViewController’s page. In such a way, the user can not just swipe left and right to see different aspect of information, but also swift up and down to see more information.

Comment: Not much jumps out at me. Two years ago I used a page view and scroll view, and my auto layout was (a) totally in code and (b) solely using anchor syntax. So first, I noted that you "mix" anchors and visual layout language - but I don't think that should be much of an issue. But is it possible that you simply have *too* much happening in a root view? Subviews with layout, stack views with layout, then a loop (`for index in 0...ix`) that adds even more constraints? I'd consider two things... (1) `UIStackViews` are made to reduce constraints and (2) break things up with a navigation controller.